# Vscode doesn't recognize Umlaute (äöü) when reading and writing files with Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, encoding

I have a Java project which reads from a .txt file and counts the frequency of every word and saves every word along with its frequency in a .stat file. The way I do this is by reading the file with a BufferedReader, using replaceAll to replace all special characters with spaces and then iterating through the words and finally writing into a .stat with a PrintWriter.

This program works fine if I run it in Eclipse.

However, if I run it in VSCode, the Umlaute (äöü) get recognized as Special characters and are removed from the words.

If I don't use a replaceAll and leave all the special characters in the text, they will get recognized and displayed normally in the .stat.

If I use `replaceAll("[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}+]")`, the Umlaute will get replaced by all kinds of weird Unicode characters (for Example Ăbermut instead of Übermut).

If I use `replaceAll("[^a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß]")`, the Umlaute will just get replaced by spaces. The same happens if I mention the Umlaute via their Unicode.

This has to be a problem with the encoding in VSCode or perhaps Powershell, as it works fine in other IDEs.

I already checked if Eclipse and VSCode use the same Jdk version, which they did. It's 17.0.5 and the only one installed on my machine.

I also tried out all the different encoding settings in VSCode and I recreated the project from scratch after changing the settings, to no avail.

Here's the code of the minimal reproducable problem:

```
import java.io.*;

public class App {
    static String s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Reader reader = new Reader();
        reader.readFile();
    }

}

public class Reader {

    public void readFile() {
        String s = null;
        File file = new File("./src/textfile.txt");

        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);) {
            s = bufferedReader.readLine();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // TODO: handle exception

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
        }

        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß]", " "));
    }
}
```

My textfile.txt contains the line "abcABCäöüÄÖÜß".
The above program outputs

```
ï»¿abcABCÃ¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã?Ã?Ã?Ã?
ï»¿      Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã?Ã?Ã?Ã?
```

Which shows that the problem is presumably in the Reader, as the glibberish Unicode symbols don't get picked up by the replaceAll.

Comment: Please show your code - it's hard to help you find a problem in the code without seeing it. I suspect it's either a) the way you read it, perhaps using a default encoding; b) the way you display it, which may depend on the console support in the IDE. To determine whether b) is a problem, you should output the UTF-16 code point for each character, e.g. by using `charAt` to access each character, convert to `int` and display that.

Comment: I added my full code. As I said, the problem is exclusive to VSCode, and if I get rid of the replaceAll, the Umlaute get transferred normally. Can you specify where/how exactly you want me to output each character?

Comment: Firstly, I'd encourage you to specify the file encoding when you construct FileReader. Next, you may need to configure VSCode to specify the encoding of your *Java* code. (Or you could use `\uxxxx` escaping for each of the non-ASCII characters in the `replaceAll` call.)

To work out exactly where the problem is, I'd encourage you to create a [mcve] - it's likely to be about 10 lines of code instead of over 120. No need to read anything from disk (unless that's where the problem is) - hard-code the input text. I'd *start* with just a hard-coded string that you print to the console.

Comment: As for "how you output each character" - just use a `for` loop to go through each index in the string, e.g. `for (int i =0; i < text.length(); i++) { System.out.println((int) text.charAt(i)); }`

Comment: hey man, i added the minimal reproducable example. The characters get messed up when I print them to the console after reading, and the replaceAll regex doesnt pick them up, which should mean that they are messed up not only in the console output, but also internally. Can you specify how exactly I should construct the FileReader with the encoding? My .txt is in UTF-8 with BOM, my java files are in normal UTF-8

Comment: You can pass a `Charset` to the `FileReader` constructor. But I *suspect* the problem is actually with the encoding for the source code. That was why I was suggested hard-coding the text using a string literal with `\uxxxx` escaping instead of reading from a file - to *really* make it minimal

Comment: Hey man, I think you solved it. I just changed all Files into UTF-8 and then passed the UTF-8 Charset into the FileReader. Now it reads the files correctly and modifies the string correctly. Before, the Reading would only work in ISO 8859-1 or W 1252 and the String modifications would only work in UTF-8, but now that I'm doing the reading in UTF-8 as well, there are no more problems. And it also works in my main project, I also used the Charset for the FileWriter. Thank you so so much man :) Should Me or You write the solution as an answer so other people can reference it?

Comment: Well that doesn't make much sense in terms of the replacements, to be honest - there are so many places that could have been problematic that it's hard for me to know what was actually wrong. I suggest you write it up, after possibly editing your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by explicitly turning all java files and all .txt files into UTF-8 encoding (in the bottom bar in VSCode), setting UTF-8 as the standard encoding in the VSCode settings and modifying both the FileReader and FileWriter to work with the UTF-8 encoding like this:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```